# Accessing ASP 2.0 control via javascript returning Null for all controls

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

Scene : I have a ASP.Net 2.0 app that I need to add functionality to. I need to loop through a gridview's items and compare them to another gridview, If they exist in the other, I must pop up a confirm message to increment the qty. I couldnt find alot on ASP 2.0 so i decided to user a hidden asp field to store what i am processing and based on that registering a clientside script to change the hidden field value and then simulate a postback (I have tried _doPostBack()). So whats happening now is I am trying to access the asp button to simulate a click, but the javascript gets a Null instance everytime. Please advise. (For the testing, i try to alert the button instance, which returns null)

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(String), "ConfirmationScript", "if (confirm('This item already exists, Increment the qty?') == true) {alert(document.getElementById('<%=btnAddSpecificLine.ClientID%>'));}", True)
```

Comment: That string will literally be put on the page. By that point, there's nothing to evaluate the ASP code `<%=btnAddSpecificLine.ClientID%>`. I believe you'll have to concatenate that script string with `btnAddSpecificLine.ClientID` instead of trying to evaluate it with `<%= %>`

Comment: It seems to return the actual <%=btnAddSpecificLine.ClientID%> in this case, So it doesnt resolve the clientid of the server control as it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try your test like this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(String), "ConfirmationScript", "if (confirm('This item already exists, Increment the qty?') == true) {alert(document.getElementById('" & btnAddSpecificLine.ClientID & "'));}", True)
```

Since you generate this code server-side - pass ClientID directly

Comment: You are the man! Thank you, Amazing how one could miss the obvious like this at times.

Comment: Very odd though as the clientid's stayed the exact same as specified in the html... would have thought that they would change since its server controls.

Comment: It changes if your control is hosted inside of some kind of a container - then the id becomes a combined ID of container ID + Control ID. Otherwise it remains the same, but it is always a good idea to use Client ID